# Extract unique values from one Column and combine in a single cell. Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have duplicate values in column (D).

How to Extract unique values from Column D and combine in a single cell (H1) without losing data, by using vba

for example: "J10P , G345 , R1 , J10G"

I tried this code to extract unique values but it is not accurate:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(4).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("H1"), Unique:=True
```

Edit: I found this code to only extract unique values and put onto column(H) ,I tested and works. now I need only code to combine cells in column H

```
' Extract unique values from Column D       
Dim D As Object, C As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
C = Range("D1:D" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(C, 1)
  D(C(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
Range("H1").Resize(D.Count) = Application.Transpose(D.keys)
```

[image]

Comment: Two concepts here to get you started. You're probably better off avoiding using the advanced autofilter. You want a `for` loop. And you want to build a string. Write code that looks at each value in column `D` and decides whether to keep it; if it keeps it, have it append it to the string you're working on (plus a space comma space, unless it's the last one). Start by figuring out how to do each of those things, and check back in if you run into trouble. Edit your question to show what you've tried and how you got stuck.

Comment: Where have you looked for the combining code?  If you look at the **answers already provided to this question**, you may find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Microsoft 365 (Office 365)  you can use following Formula to get the desired result. I assume you want space on either sides of comma.

Edit - Thanks to Máté Juhász for their suggestion.

```
 =TEXTJOIN(" , ",TRUE,UNIQUE(D1:D7))
```

VBA Based solution based on Code selected by OP.

In Excel Press <kbd>ATL</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA Editor. Insert a Module and add following two User Defined Functions (UDF).

```
Function UNIQUE1()

Application.Volatile
Dim D As Object, C As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
C = Range("D1:D" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(C, 1)
  D(C(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

UNIQUE1 = Application.Transpose(D.keys)


End Function


Function TEXTJOIN1(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As Boolean, ParamArray cell_ar() As Variant)
    Application.Volatile
    For Each cellrng In cell_ar
        For Each cell In cellrng
            If ignore_empty = False Then
                result = result & cell & delimiter
            Else
                If cell <> "" Then
                    result = result & cell & delimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Next cellrng
    TEXTJOIN1 = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delimiter))
End Function
```

This creates two user defined functions named UNIQUE1 & TEXTJOIN1. Save and exit VBA Editor.

Now in H1 put the following formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN1(" , ", TRUE, unique1())
```

[image]

Note the following

- Your code is slightly modified and a UDF is created out of it. Also it uses Column 4 for column D `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row` because in my example there's no full table. I have only populated column D
- `Application.Volatile` is added to make it auto calculate whenever applicable
- TEXTJOIN1 UDF is needed because your version of Excel does not have this function built-in.
- Save the workbook as .xlsm Macro Enabled

Comment: Your formula is overcomplicated. `TEXTJOIN(" , ",TRUE,UNIQUE(D1:D7))` would do the same.

Comment: @Máté Juhász Oh yes! Substitute and Transpose are not necessary! Thanks

Comment: I have office 2016 , so I tried VBA option , But it is not working. I got this error in cell (H1)  #Name?

Comment: See the edit. Since your version does not have TEXTJOIN function built-in, a UDF is needed for the same.

Comment: Now works excellent . Many thanks for all your help 